# How to create an expression that is not greater than 2 and less than 1 in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, expression

Good morning. Sorry for the indelicate question, but how to create an expression that is not greater than 2 and less than 1 in Objective C
My code dosn't work

```
if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]<=2.0 || [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]>=1.0)
```

Comment: Did you mean "less than or equal to 2" and "greater than or equal to 1"? Your current wording is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

`||` is the operator for logical OR, which isn't what you want. You need `&&`, the operator for logical AND.So now your code will look like this:

```
if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]<=2.0 && [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]>=1.0)
```

Comment: I try its not worked, just max 2 , but i still can change to 0 (

Answer (score -1):

Let's break that down...

**an expression that is not greater than 2**

```
if (! (someValue > 2)) {
  // someValue is not greater than 2
}
```

However, "not greater than 2" is the same thing as "less-than-or-equal to 2" so...

```
if (someValue <= 2) {
  // someValue is not greater than 2
}
```

Now, for the second part...

**an expression that is less than 1**

```
if (someValue < 1) {
  // someValue is less than 1
}
```

And...

**an expression that is not greater than 2 and less than 1.**

```
if ((someValue <= 2) && (someValue < 1)) {
  // someValue is not greater than 2 and less than 1
}
```

However, if you think about it, any number that is less than 1 will also be "not greater than 2" so you don't even need that part.

```
if (someValue < 1) {
  // someValue is less than 1... and it is also not greater than 2
}
```